# How to create a circular list in one line of code?

Tags: python, list, circular-list, pairwise

Given the following list:

```py
labels = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
```

I wish I could obtain the following by using just one line of code:

```py
['0-1', '1-2', '2-3', '3-4', '4-0']
```

I can do this with 2 lines of code:

```py
pairwise_labels = [f"{i}-{i+1}" for i in range(len(labels)-1)]
pairwise_labels.append(f"{len(labels)-1}-0")
```

With just one line, my code will be drastically reduced, as I always need to create an `if` for the last case to close the loop.

Comment: Um, you say *"Given the following list"* but then you completely ignore the elements of that list and use the list solely for its length? What's up with that?

Comment: I did this because what I want is to do a circular iteration through any list. Sorry for the misunderstanding of the question, but the answers here will already help me a lot.

Answer (score 4):

One option would be to use [`pairwise`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.pairwise) (*New in version 3.10*) :

```
from itertools import pairwise

labels = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]

pairwise_labels = [f"{x}-{y}" for x, y in pairwise(labels + [labels[0]])]
```

Output :

```
print(pairwise_labels)

#['0-1', '1-2', '2-3', '3-4', '4-0']
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do this in one line using modular arithmetic.

```
pairwise_labels = [f"{labels[i]}-{labels[(i+1)%len(labels)]}" for i in range(len(labels))]
```

Comment: Or without: `[f"{labels[i]}-{labels[i+1]}" for i in range(-len(labels), 0)]`

Answer (score 2):

Your one liner:

```py
pairwise_labels = [f'{a}-{b}' for a, b in zip(labels, labels[1:] + [labels[0]])]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can slice your list:

```
>>> [f'{i}-{j}' for i, j in zip(labels, labels[1:] + labels[:1])]

['0-1', '1-2', '2-3', '3-4', '4-0']
```

Answer (score 1):

You can leverage Python's ability to use negative indexes:

```
labels = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]

pl = [f"{a}-{labels[i]}" for i,a in enumerate(labels,1-len(labels))]

print(pl)

['0-1', '1-2', '2-3', '3-4', '4-0']
```